# How to have a foreign diploma recognized in France?

Tags: france, students, refugees

I am helping a Sudanese refugee living in France (in Paris) who wants to take his studies up again. He got a secondary school certificate in Sudan and needs his diploma recognized in France. I found [this website](http://www.ciep.fr/enic-naric-page/reconnaissance-diplome-etranger-documents-delivres) explaining which document he can get, but I don’t know how to proceed to make a proper request. How can he get this document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To request the certificate of equivalence, you and your friend have to follow [this link](https://phoenix.ciep.fr/inscriptions/) (preferably not using Firefox, which makes the website buggy).
He will have to give his identity and an email address. This address is important because it is where the certificate will be sent to him. After that, you’ll be asked a few questions and finally, you’ll have to upload :

- his ID or an application document for asylum or the refugee status
- his qualification certificate(s) or diploma(s) in the original language
- a document showing proof of the official duration of the studies leading to his graduation (this may be a diploma supplement, marks sheets, certificates of attendance, etc.)

If for some reason one of the above documents can’t be uploaded, it is worth trying to upload a text document explaining why instead.

When this is done, after some time (usually a few weeks I believe), he will be sent the certificate (except if the CIEP found his folder incomplete, which would be notified to him by email).

[This detailed guide](https://www.resome.org/attachment/803138/) (in English) can be helpful when filling the form. If any additional information is of help, both of you are very welcome to come to meet Resome volunteers every Friday from 2.30pm to 5.30pm or Saturday from 10am to 1pm at the following address :

> Maison des Initiatives étudiantes
>
> 50 Rue des Tournelles, 75003 Paris
>
> (métro : Bastille).

When doing so, be sure to bring all the documents he has about his studies/diplomas (preferably in numeric format).

As for taking his studies up again, you may find useful information in [this other guide](https://www.resome.org/attachment/852234/) (in English and in French). Again, feel free to come and talk to us about it.